# Xamarin iOS NavigationController in each tab of TabBarController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Is it possible such that I can have a navigation controller in each of my tabs of a TabBarController while using Xamarin iOS? I've currently setup my storyboard like so (for simplicity, I'm using a single tab)

`TabBarController -> NavigationController -> UITableViewController`

In my UITableViewController, the following code in my `ViewDidLoad` method does not change the title nor add the desired button to the top navigation. Have I set up something wrong?

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    Console.WriteLine("view did load");
    Title = "My custom title";

    NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(
        new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, (sender, args) =>
        {
            PerformSegue("CreateRecordSegue", this);
        })
    , true);
}
```

Image of storyboard is here: https://ibb.co/m7qq85

Comment: Please share screenshot of storyboard

Comment: @NinjaHattori I uploaded an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to:

1) Remove the navigation controller that leads into the tab bar controller

2) Create a segue from the home page into the tab bar controller, making the segue type to **replace** (instead of push)